# Trouble Encrypting/Decrypting string in C# with random IV

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I am rewriting some code to have a random IV that is prepended to my encrypted string. The encryption I think is correct (can't decrypt so I'm not 100% sure), but the problem is when I run the decrypt function, I get an exception

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The input data is not a complete block.'
```

Below is the source code. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? I think the error is in the binaryWritr.Write call, but after several iterations, I'm not making progress. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static string EncryptString(string inputText)
    {
        using(var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider() {
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        }) {
            var input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputText);
            aes.GenerateIV();
            var iv = aes.IV;
            using(var encrypter = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, iv))
            using(var cipherStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                using(var tCryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cipherStream, encrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                using(var tBinaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(tCryptoStream)) {
                    //Prepend IV to data
                    cipherStream.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);
                    tBinaryWriter.Write(input);
                    tCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                }

                return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

    public static string DecryptString(string inputText)
    {
        var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider() {
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        };

        //get first 16 bytes of IV and use it to decrypt
        var iv = new byte[16];
        Array.Copy(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputText), 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);

        using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            using(var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            using(var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(cs)) {
                //Decrypt Cipher Text from Message
                binaryWriter.Write(
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputText),
                    iv.Length,
                    inputText.Length - iv.Length
                );
            }

            return Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Comment: First problem: your encryptor converts the resulting binary data to text using Convert.ToBase64String. On the reverse front, you're using Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes. I'd expect to see a call to Convert.FromBase64String... See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/01/20/diagnosing-issues-with-reversible-data-transformations/ for help diagnosing this sort of thing.

Comment: The are several mismatches in your code: in EncryptString your last action is Convert.ToBase64String, therefore in DecryptString your first action should be Convert.FromBase64String (which should be used where you have your second Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes); in EncryptString you encode your plaintext as UTF-8, but in DecryptString you decode your plaintext as your operating system's ANSI encoding (= Encoding.Default).

Comment: Beneath @Jon Skeet's very good comment I would dump the iv directly after generation in hex code and compare it to the first 16 bytes of the Base64 decoded cipherstring to be for shure that both are identical.

Comment: Both methods use the (random) key generated during the instantiation of `AesCryptoServiceProvider`, i.e. encryption and decryption are performed with different keys.